# Which parser JSX uses?

Tags: parsing, jsx

As mention in name `JSX` and it's restriction like must have closing tag etc.
I think `JSX` uses `XML` parser.
if uses `XML` then why choose `XML not HTML` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/):

> "JSX Specification: XML-LIKE SYNTAX EXTENSION TO ECMASCRIPT"

To answer your question: "why choose XML not HTML", because this allows it to be a superset of HTML with the inclusion of user defined tags.  For example it allows you to define a "MyApp" tag (component) and use it: `<MyApp name="some name" />`.  As it's an "XML-LIKE SYNTAX EXTENSION TO ECMASCRIPT" this allows you to use it along side javascript:

```
function calculatedComplexName() {

    return "some complex name";
}

<MyApp name={calculatedComplexName()}/>
```